# htaccess - codeigniter issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter.  My current htaccess file works fine on my local environment - but when I load it onto the server I am using I get a 404 page not found error.

I am a complete newbie with htaccess - so you might have to spell it out for me. One thing that might affect this - I have several sites on the same domain right now - so the current site is in a sub-directory called "ripped2"

Here is my htaccess:

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check .htaccess file permission on live server it should be 755 not 777 because sometime on 777 it`s get an error...please check this

Answer (score 0):

Which version of codeigniter are u using ....if you are using latest codeigniter 3.0 then:

- change your controller and model  filename with starting capital letter for example if you have controller name as : home.php then change it to Home.php ..
- do this to all you filename of controller and model ..

Hope it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you using? For some servers you might need to have a web.config file in the root of your website... Read this [Need a web.config file instead of .htaccess for codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624748/need-a-web-config-file-instead-of-htaccess-for-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

you should add...

```
RewriteBase /ripped2
```

Comment: You should add... an explanation, what is this doing, and why is it needed.