# Url rewrite not working for php mvc website hosted in IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I have configured PHP mvc website at iis
the website url is http://abc.def.com/workingdir/index.php
I have provided href ="Steps" for a link, so the working URL should be  http://abc.def.com/workingdir/steps

But it gives me 404 not found error.

instead when i manually type http://abc.def.com/workingdir/index.php/steps

or give href = "index.php/steps" it works fine . But i dont need index.php in the URL
it should be simply accessible with the link click by http://abc.def.com/workingdir/steps

Please guide.

Many Thanks,

Comment: you have to set `RewriteBase` inside `.htaccess` eg . `RewriteBase /root/domain/workingdir/`. Make sure your `RewriteEngine` should be on.

Comment: as i have installed the website at iis i have excluded htaccess and included web.config. do i need to include .htaccess?

Comment: you have to convert RewriteBase .htaccess code according to `web.config`

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624748/need-a-web-config-file-instead-of-htaccess-for-codeigniter link for more.

Comment: I tried it with all the options its not working